# How do I traverse an inner node using SAX in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, sax

I'm quite new to Nokogiri and Ruby and seeking a little help.

I am parsing a very large XML file using `class MyDoc < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document`. Now I want to traverse the inner part of a block.

Here's the format of my XML file:

```
<Content id="83087">
    <Title></Title>
    <PublisherEntity id="1067">eBooksLib</PublisherEntity>
    <Publisher>eBooksLib</Publisher>
    ......
</Content>
```

I can already tell if the "Content" tag is found, now I want to know how to traverse inside of it. Here's my shortened code:

```
class MyDoc < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  #check the start element. set flag for each element
  def start_element name, attrs = []
    if(name == 'Content')
      #get the <Title>
      #get the <PublisherEntity>
      #get the Publisher
    end
  end


  def cdata_block(string)
    characters(string)
  end 

  def characters(str)
    puts str
  end
end
```

Comment: Why SAX? There is a good chance you're looking for Nokogiri.XML instead.

Comment: the xml file is at least 1GIG so I want it to be memory efficient.

Comment: +1 yes, that is actually a good reason to use SAX

Comment: https://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trickier to do with SAX. I think the solution will need to look something like this:

```
class MyDoc < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  def start_element name, attrs = []
    @inside_content = true if name == 'Content'
    @current_element = name
  end

  def end_element name
    @inside_content = false if name == 'Content'
    @current_element = nil
  end

  def characters str
    puts "#{@current_element} - #{str}" if @inside_content && %w{Title PublisherEntity Publisher}.include?(@current_element)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Purists may disagree with me, but the way I've been doing it is to use Nokogiri to traverse the huge file, and then use XmlSimple to work with a smaller object in the file. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'xmlsimple'

def isend(node)
   return (node.node_type == Nokogiri::XML::Reader::TYPE_END_ELEMENT)
end

reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(File.open('database.xml', 'r'))

# traverse the file looking for tag "content"
reader.each do |node|
   next if node.name != 'content' || isend(node)
   # if we get here, then we found start of node 'content',
   # so read it into an array and work with the array:
   content = XmlSimple.xml_in(node.outer_xml())
   title = content['title'][0]
   # ...etc.
end
```

This works very well for me. Some may object to mixing SAX and non-SAX (nokogiri and XmlSimple) in the same code, but for my purposes, it gets the job done with minimal hassle.